# Switch between SKScene and UIViewControllers without memory rising

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

I have 3 UIViewControllers. The first controller - Menu Game. The second - Game. The third - Game Over controller.
In the second controller I have SKView with one scene of my game. 
I created segue in storyboard between the button (Start Game) in 1-st controller and 2-nd controller. And segue between 3-rd controller (tap gesture) and 1-st controller. All segues are "Show".

In 2-nd controller I create follow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showGameOverViewController", name: "showGameOverViewController", object: nil)
}
func showGameOverViewController() -> Void {
   performSegueWithIdentifier("gameOverSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Then when I need to switch from scene (in GameScene.swift) to 3-rd controller I call follow:

```
self.view?.presentScene(nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showGameOverViewController", object: nil)
```

This way works, but works bad.. When I tap the button in 1-st controller the 2-nd controller then follow method is calling and the scene is initialising:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   let skView = self.view as SKView
   if skView.scene == nil {
      let gameScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
      gameScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
      skView.presentScene(gameScene)
   }
}
```

So I have a problem. When I finish my game, go to 1-st controller again and tap Start Game button then memory of my application is rising! 
And when I go from Scene to 3-rd controller then the memory of my app is rising. The rise of memory happens again and again.

I chose this way because my SKS editor doesn't works and I decided not to create Menu Scene and Game Over Scene programmatically. I thought to create Menu in Interface Builder would be better and faster and I had decided to try go this way. And I'm interested in the answer to solve my problem.

Please help me.. How to switch between SKScene and UIViewControllers without memory rising?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198809/my-navigation-controller-count-keeps-growing/21198862#21198862

Comment: Not quite. There is a part of my problew. But I'm interestiong in memory leak in SKView..

Comment: In any case, your segue from 3rd controller to first is definitely a problem that should be fixed.

Comment: Do you have a memory leak? What evidence do you have of that? Rising memory use as you switch controllers is not a memory leak. That rising memory use is caused by the problem I pointed out with the link.